# App force closes after choosing image from gallery

Tags: android

I do not know where the error is, my codes are copy-pasted from a project that is working fine. Picture can be taken and saved into gallery, but when I want to load it up into an imageview, the app crashes. Been looking around for answers but all of them do not work for me. Here is the log when the app crashes,

```
09-07 10:17:06.371 745-745/henderson.application E/BitmapFactory: Unable to 
decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20170907_101702.jpg: open failed: EACCES 
(Permission denied)
09-07 10:17:06.381 745-828/henderson.application D/mali_winsys: 
new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1536x2048]-format:1
09-07 10:17:06.411 745-745/henderson.application I/Timeline: Timeline: 
Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@54ccc23 time:51142783
09-07 10:17:13.501 745-745/henderson.application D/ViewRootImpl: 
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
09-07 10:17:13.541 745-745/henderson.application D/ViewRootImpl: 
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
09-07 10:17:13.726 745-745/henderson.application V/ActivityThread: 
updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{b1c68e8 
token=android.os.BinderProxy@54ccc23 
{henderson.application/henderson.application.Application_admin_1}} show : 
true
09-07 10:17:15.281 745-745/henderson.application E/BitmapFactory: Unable to 
decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20170907_101702.jpg: open failed: EACCES 
(Permission denied)
09-07 10:17:15.281 745-745/henderson.application D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting 
down VM
09-07 10:17:15.281 745-745/henderson.application E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: 
henderson.application, PID: 745
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/526 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {henderson.application/henderson.application.Application_admin_1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4927)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4970)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:223)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1851)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at henderson.application.Application_admin_1.onActivityResult(Application_admin_1.java:82)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7138)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4923)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4970) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1851) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

here is the method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECTED_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                image_file_path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                File f = new File(image_file_path);
                if (f.exists()){
                    Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_file_path);
                    //Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(selectedImage);
                    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(selectedImage);
                    if (btnNo == 1) {
                        imageViewPLRD.setBackground(d);

                    } else if (btnNo == 2) {
                        imageViewIC.setBackground(d);

                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and here is the xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contextClickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPLRD"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#e4e4e4" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewIC"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#e4e4e4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutImage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Insert PLRD"
            android:id="@+id/btnPLRD"
            android:onClick="btnPLRDOnClick"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Insert IC"
            android:onClick="btn2OnClick"
            android:id="@+id/btnIC"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I run the code on debug mode and saw that the declared Bitmap selectedImage is null after that line, but i do not see whats wrong.

Comment: okay i just saw the log has that permission denied, i have that <uses-permission> tag already in but im not exactly sure if its the right one....

Comment: `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '... ImageView.setBackground(...)' on a null object reference` - That crash is because `imageViewPLRD` or `imageViewIC` or both are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one...i already use this many times....  and also check permission

permission in AndroidManifest.xml==>

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Calling method=====>

```
private void getImagefromGallery() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                RESULT_FROM_GALLERY);
    } else {
        Intent mediaChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        mediaChooser.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(mediaChooser, RESULT_FROM_GALLERY);
    }
}
```

On activity result method====>

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (resultCode) {
        case RESULT_OK:

            if (requestCode == RESULT_FROM_GALLERY) {
                String picturePath = "";

                Uri selectedUri = data.getData();
                Log.d("videopathyri===>", String.valueOf(selectedUri));


                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivityCrop.class);
                intent.putExtra("baseimage", selectedUri);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
         }
        }
```

Comment: i dont think i will be trying this method, i have already solved the permissions part, now im having null object reference when the line imageView.setImageResource(d); runs, even though d is not null

Comment: you put wrong code to set image that why null pointer error comes...try this code====>                                                                                                                         `imageView.setImageDrawable(res);`     _or_ `imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

and below code is your on activity result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                image_view.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have an error while trying that, says decodeFile cannot be applied to InputStream

Comment: refer another code may help you : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

Comment: okay, added String.valueOf(image) to correct it, now it says nullpointer

Comment: the code samples in the link you gave is exactly the same as mine @Bapusaheb Shinde